# Custom RSS does not work for categories and tags

Tags: rss, feed

We have a custom RSS in our web.
It works normally on Main page and post - https://www.kryptonovinky.cz/feed/spotify

But in categories and tags it does not work https://www.kryptonovinky.cz/category/podcasty/feed/spotify
redirect to https://www.kryptonovinky.cz/category/podcasty/feed

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

```php
/* This code initializes the custom RSS Feeds for your website*/
add_action('init', 'customRSS');
function customRSS(){
        add_feed('spotify', 'customRSSFunc');
}
 
/* This code seeks the template for your RSS feed */
function customRSSFunc(){
        get_template_part('rss', 'spotify');
}
```